# How to modify the gradients in tensorflow keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I hope to use tensorflow to build the model for classification task. The last layer of the model is softmax layer. I can provide the gradients with respect to the logits. How can I modify the gradients for the logits and let the model to compute the gradients of other weights by backward propagation automatically?

I understand the tensorflow can compute the gradient automatically once I provide the loss function. The problem is the loss function is high complex, and it is almost impossible to let the computer compute the gradient automatically. But I can wrote some functions to provide the gradient.

Comment: What do you mean by `The problem is the loss function is high complex, and it is almost impossible to let the computer compute the gradient automatically. But I can wrote some functions to provide the gradient.`? Can u give us its formula?

Comment: Hi @Marton First you need to define the Model in which your network architecture using high-level API.Ensure that last layer is softmax layer.
Second think is the loss function you can split it into components and handle them separately.
Compute Gradients for Logits Manually:-You can use tf.GradientTape() to record operations and compute gradients. After that combine the manually computed gradients for logits with the automatically computed gradients for other weights and biases as needed. This could involve scaling, clipping, or simply adding them together.